Disable Drop inside DataGrid cell during edit mode
My application is a wine bottle/wine rack tracking tool that allows the user to quickly look up the location of a specific bottle of wine inside a collection of wine racks.  I have drag and drop from the list of wine bottles (a DataGrid) to a wine rack (user control) by sending the bottle's ID (int) to the destination control.  The problem is when the user clicks on a cell in the DataGrid to edit it's contents the drag drop executes and inserts the bottle ID into the text where the user clicks.
Here is my UI:
Application overview
This is what happens when I single click on a cell to edit:
Bug
If the user clicks multiple times on the cell I get this exception:
Exception Unhandled
Below is the XAML for the DataGrid:
<DataGrid Name="DGBottleList"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Grid.Row="0"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source=mainWindowBottles}" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
          SelectionChanged="DGBottleList_OnSelectionChanged"
          CurrentCellChanged="DGBottleList_CellChanged" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          Padding="0,0,0,0"
          Margin="0,0,5,0">


    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DGBottleListRow_DoubleClick"/>
            <EventSetter Event="MouseMove"        Handler="DGBottleListRow_MouseMove"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"     
                            Binding="{Binding Name}"     
                            Width="SizeToCells" 
                            MinWidth="45"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vineyard" 
                            Binding="{Binding Vineyard}" 
                            Width="SizeToCells" 
                            MinWidth="55"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vintage"  
                            Binding="{Binding Vintage}"  
                            Width="SizeToCells" 
                            MinWidth="50"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Varietal" 
                            Binding="{Binding Varietal}" 
                            Width="SizeToCells" 
                            MinWidth="50"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type"     
                            Binding="{Binding TypeText}" 
                            Width="SizeToCells" 
                            MinWidth="35" 
                            IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Region"   
                            Binding="{Binding Region}"   
                            Width="SizeToCells" 
                            MinWidth="50"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rack"     
                            Binding="{Binding RackName}" 
                            Width="SizeToCells" 
                            MinWidth="35" 
                            IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Copy Bottle"      Click="DGBottleList_CopyBottle"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Copy Many..."     Click="DGBottleList_CopyMany"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add or Edit Note" Click="DGBottleList_AddNote"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Remove from rack" Click="DGBottleList_RemoveFromRack"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Delete"           Click="DGBottleList_Delete"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>

And here is my MouseMove:
protected void DGBottleListRow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    if (sender is not DataGridRow row)
        return;

    if (row.Item is not WineBottle movedBottle)
        return;

    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(row, movedBottle.ID.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Move);
}

My understanding is the default AllowDrop should be False on the DataGrid and it's children.  I have tried manually setting the AllowDrop to false on the DataGrid, DataGridRow, DataGridCell and the TextBlock child.  I have tried assigning a handler method to all the before mentioned UI Elements that simply displays a MessageBox when a Drop happens to narrow down where the problem is coming from.  I have not been able to get the MessageBox to fire yet.  I am at a loss and any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Sounds like your drag&drop is not implemented correctly. It looks like you are not checking the drop target. It looks like clicking on the DataGrid triggers the drag&drop operation (because mouse is down and moving). Then when the mouse is released, because the user meant to edit the cell, you drop the ID into the cell. It should be easy to avoid that. For example, set a flag that drag&drop has been initiated (in mouse move) but do not start it yet. Then wait until MouseLeave to call DragDrop.DoDragDrop. Still, you need to check the drop target.

So better handle DragDrop.QueryContinueDrag and cancel the drag operation if the mouse button is released over the DataGrid. It would be helpful if you could show your complete drag&drop implementation (a minimal example). Note that the drop target in this special case is a TextBox (the cell edit template is active). Therefore, AllowDrop must be set to FALSE on the TextBox. that's why setting it on the DataGrid doesn't show any effect. AllowDrop is TRUE by default for the TextBox (the common default is FALSE).

@BionicCode, Streeter provided a quick simple solution but I like yours as well.  I'm fairly new to C# and WPF, with no formal education other than a few "teach yourself WPF" books and the MS documentation so I'm still learning.  I hadn't seen any examples of implementing drag drop that way.  I'll be using it from here on out if appropriate for the situation (and checking the drop target).  Thanks!

DataGridRow has an IsEditing dependency property. You could check if row is not being edited before DragDrop.DoDragDrop
if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && !row.IsEditing)
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(row, movedBottle.ID.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Move);


That did it!  Thanks Streeter.
